# faster amfPHP alternative

Tags: php, json, amf, amfphp

i'm a little shocked how slow amfPHP is. 
I've compared the overall performance of AMF and JSON Requests.

Both way's where measured from the beginning of the request till having strongly typed data on Actionscript Site.

The JSON way was always more than twice faster.

I'm normaly running on a Java Backend, but now i'm forced to PHP.

Does someone knows a better support of AMF in the PHP world. FlashBuilder comes with integrated support of Zend AMF. But it is slow as amfPHP.

THX for Help

Comment: I'm the author of SabreAMF but its not longer maintained, and wouldn't recommend using it. It was pretty much the basis for Zend AMF. Out of curiosity.. why not use json? I feel it's a much better choice nowadays.

Comment: Zend is slower than amf and complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a free, fast and extremely reliable PHP AMF3 extension:

http://neoxic.me/php-amf3/

It provides two native functions - amf3_encode() and amf3_decode(). No mess, pure speed!

Answer (score 1):

AMF is complex, so it's inevitable that parsing it in PHP is slow. Take a look at adding a PHP extension that does it in C: http://baguetteamf.com . (disclaimer, I created that project)

Answer (score 1):

You will can use Apache Thrift, as3 and php supported.